# Why my state do not get update while in parent was updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try understanding render, re-render and the process on react when updating state.
I read on this article: [kentcdodds](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/use-state-lazy-initialization-and-function-updates)

I have Component like this.

```
function DelayedCounter() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
  console.log('DelayedCounter', count)
  function increment() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('increment', count)
      setCount(count + 1)
    }, 2000)
  }
  return <button onClick={increment}>{count}</button>
}
```

I tried clicking the button 3 times quickly. And this is the result on my Chrome browser.

```
increment 0
DelayedCounter 1
increment 0
DelayedCounter 1
increment 0
```

I know we can use prevState with callback function, but I am just wondering Why **count's state** in **parent's component** get updated to be 1? But inside the **increment's function** the **count's state** still being 0?

Could you explain it?
Thank you.

Comment: Your answer is explained exactly here in the [doc - *React batches state updates*](https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates). Please read it throughly how react state updates over the time.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried clicking the button 3 times quickly.

Since the function has a `setTimeout` to perform its operation after two seconds then "quickly" was probably faster than that.  So all three clicks took place from the same rendered component.  At that time the value of `count` was `0`, so all three instances of `console.log('increment', count)` output a value of `0`.

> Why count's state in parent's component get updated to be 1?

Same reason.  All three clicks were based on a value of `0`, and all three clicks incremented that value by `1`.  So all three of them set the state to `1`.

Basically, all three clicks did this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('increment', 0)
  setCount(0 + 1)
}, 2000)
```

That is, because the function effectively has a closure around the value of `0` for `count` (which itself is a `const` and can't change until the component re-renders and re-declares it from the backing state anyway, closure or otherwise), each click simply:

1. Outputs the value `0`
2. Queues a state update to `0 + 1`

After the two (or so) seconds pass, the three queued state updates are processed and each one of them updates state to the same value.

---

> I know we can use prevState with callback function

Which indeed is how this was addressed by React.  Perhaps a less confusing example is something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setCount(count + 1);
}
```

Without any context or knowledge of React, one may look at this isolated piece of code and conclude that `count` (starting at `0`) will be `10` after the loop.  But in fact it will be `1` *after the re-render*.

The re-render doesn't occur until state is actually updated, and state isn't actually updated until the thread finishes this loop (and anything else it's doing).  So every iteration of this loop is *effectively* doing this:

```
setCount(0 + 1);
```

All ten state updates are queued, all ten are processed after the loop has already completed, and all ten set state to the same new value.  As implied by your question, you're probably already aware of the solution:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setCount(prev => prev + 1);
}
```

In this case all ten state updates are still queued and will be processed after the loop has finished (all still resulting in *one* re-render of the component), but the difference is that the operation isn't relying on the value of the const `count` but is instead relying on the value of the backing state *as it changes* throughout the batch of state updates.

Answer (score 0):

In React, state updates are asynchronous. When you call `setCount(count + 1)` in the `increment` function, React does not immediately update the `count` state. Instead, it schedules an update and continues with the rest of the code. Therefore, when you log the `count` immediately after calling `setCount`, you might not see the updated state.

Sequence of events in your code:

1.You click the button.

2.`increment` function is called.

3.`setTimeout` is set for 2000 milliseconds, and the current value of `count` is captured (which is 0).

4.You click the button again before the `setTimeout` fires.

5.Another `setTimeout` is set with the current value of `count` (still 0).

6.This process repeats for each click before the first `setTimeout` fires.

7.After 2000 milliseconds, the first `setTimeout` fires. The log inside the callback shows `"increment 0"` because it captured the state at the time it was set.

Comment: State updates being asynchronous is not the (direct) problem. Even if the update wasn't asynchronous, it's impossible for `count` to change in the current frame as it's a `const`.